# How-to open a splitted terminal with commands in it automatically

Tags: linux, unix, split, terminal

I often have to connect to different web servers and to check the log files.

To do that, I usually open up a terminal, splited vertically and display the error logs and access logs side-by-side.

However, I always have to repeat the same steps over and over again to do that manually. Currently, the terminal split is done graphically (I'm using iTerm) by I'm pretty sure something exists to do that in a "raw" terminal.

Basically, I'd like to be able to open two different commands simultaneously in separate splited views within the same terminal. My goal is to automate that so that I can execute it easily on any server I have to deal with.

I really don't know how to proceed/which tools to use to do that. Do you know how I could achieve that ? (I believe `screen`can be splited, but I'm not sure how to start it with the two different commands running without other human interaction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure `screen` to start with two windows, each running a command. For example, try

```
cat > scr <<'EOF'
split
screen less /etc/hosts
focus
screen less $HOME/.bashrc
EOF
screen -c scr
```

See `man screen` for details.